# Assigning dynamic values to a lookup field

Tags: forms, dynamic, case, crm, lookup

I am creating a dialog that, depending on the user's input, asks different questions. Once it has all the details, I create a new record (case) and fill it with a new case form with the user's details.

I am mainly doing this to avoid unnecessary form fields. For example, if a customer calls for general support, we don't want to ask them about which store they purchased item from, as the customer might just want to know what time we close. However, if a customer calls complaining about a product they bought, then we want to capture details of product, store purchased from, fault type etc...

The issue occurs when I am trying to assign some of the dynamic values to fields in a new case form. The fields that lookup types are not allowing me to assign values dynamically. I don't want to create new fields, as that will change all the relationships and dependencies.

**Is there any solution to assigning these values to a lookup dynamically?**

Comment: could you post what language you are trying to do this in?

Comment: I am using on premise CRM 2011 if that is what you are asking for?

Comment: You should be able to assign the fields as you do with any workflow step. What exactly is 'not allowing' you?

Comment: In dialog steps I am adding 'Create new record' for Cases. Then I click on set properties. This brings up a form which is a typical Case form. Clicked on title field in form and then on the right hand panel selecting contact from the 1st drop down menu and then title from the 2nd drop down menu. Then clicking on add to put that dynamic value in to form (highlighted yellow). When I try to do the same thing for the field that is lookup, I can select Contact from the first dromdown menu but nothing comes up in the second drop down menu.

Comment: @kmria, I was under the impression that crm was a library under another language, not it's own language. That's why I asked what language you are using.

Comment: Just wanted to updated everyone on my finding for this issue. The field I created was optional set and I made sure that my dialog field is the same optional set with same label and value. The mistake I made was that the CRM field was integar and in dialog I was choosing text as data type. As soon as I changed it from text to integar, I was able to assign value dynamically. Thanks for all your help and apologies for terrible grammer!